Can't weight paint
I tried to rig a character but when I move a bone, my character stretched and fold into himself and I don't really know why.
After looking around, I saw that weight paint may help my character to not fold but I can't override the color but on the right of my character it works. Do you know if the weight painting can help and why is it not working ? 

hello please share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/

@moonboots thanks, here is the file: 
I finally can weight paint on it (I forgot to apply the mirror modifier) but on pose mode, when I move a bone (like the arm) it still stretch the body..

Reparent with Automatic Weights and it seems to work fine, it will need some little corrections in Weight Paint mode though

You can select your model and press Alt+P, then select Clear Parent to remove the automatic weight paint. Try pressing Ctrl+A and selecting Scale to apply the scale. Then, you can rig it again with automatic weights. Additionally, you might encounter problems with normals if you mirrored your character. Enter Edit Mode, select all faces, then press Alt+N and choose Recalculate Outside to ensure all normals face outward.
